# Finding limit of $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor $

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Consider $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor $ . Now find value of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) $ . I know that if $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = -1$ but I don't know whether it is true or not in the infinity .

Comment: $x\in \mathbb Z\implies f(x)=x+(-x)=0$.   $x\notin \mathbb Z\implies f(x)=-1$ so the limit does not exist.

Comment: @lulu You are wrong . We are talking about limit not value of function .

Comment: lulu 's point is more or less the same as boaz 's answer, it boils down to the fact that the function do not converge because for arbitrarily large values, $f$ jumps between the values $0$ and $-1$.

Comment: No, I'm not wrong.  $f(x)$ is a function which hits $0$ for arbitrarily large $x$ and it hits $-1$ for arbitrarily large $x$.  That means it can not reach a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: @lulu Can you explain why this happens ? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+floor(x)+%2B+floor(-x)+as+x+to+infinity

Comment: Sure.  Wolfram Alpha made a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no limit when $x\to\infty$. Consider the sequences 
$$
x_n=n\qquad y_n=n+\frac{1}{2}
$$
Both sequence tend to $\infty$, but notice that $f(x_n)=0$ while $f(y_n)=-1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Why $f(y_n)=-1$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W $\lfloor n+1/2\rfloor=n$ and $\lfloor -(n+1/2)\rfloor=-n-1$

Comment: $\lfloor n+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor -n-\frac{1}{2}\rfloor=n+(-n-1)=-1$

Comment: @boaz So why wolfram alpha says that it has limit ?!

Comment: e.g. $\lfloor 3.5\rfloor=3$

Comment: @boaz Take a look : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+floor(x)+%2B+floor(-x)+as+x+to+infinity

Comment: Perhaps the software did not recognize that this is an integral lower value.

Comment: No , it is right .

Comment: I don't know...I would recommend less to rely on WA and more on our head (:

Answer (score 1):

Defining with $ \left\{ x \right\}$ the fractional part of $x$, i.e.
$$
x = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\}
$$
and denoting by $[P]$ the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$
then we have that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 f(x) = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor { - x} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  - \left\lceil x \right\rceil  =  - \left( {\left\lceil x \right\rceil  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } \right) =  \\ 
  =  - \left\lceil {\left\{ x \right\}} \right\rceil  =  - 1 + \left[ {x \in Z} \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   { - 1} & {\left| {\;x \notin Z} \right.}  \\
   0 & {\left| {\;x \in Z} \right.}  \\
\end{array}} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

and the limit for $x \to \infty$ does not exist.

Comment: So the limit is $\infty$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: no, the limit is undefined. I have reshaped my answer to better clear the meaning of the final expression with the Iverson bracket.